# how to do calculation inside text field flutter as same as excel cell

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

for example, I want to write "5 + 3" in text field in flutter app, then press enter, after that, I want from application to convert the input to the result, I mean convert "5 + 3" to "8".

is there any way to do that in flutter?

thanks in advance for the help.

I searched about way in google, but did not find any thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a `TextField` that calls an evaluation function when user submit the input, by having the evaluation inside the callback of [`onSubmitted`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextField/onSubmitted.html). After that, set the `TextField`'s controller text to the result of the evaluation. To evaluate the calculation from the input, you can use a package like [math_parser](https://pub.dev/packages/math_parser).

```dart
import 'package:math_parser/math_parser.dart';

class SampleWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const SampleWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<SampleWidget> createState() => _SampleWidgetState();
}

class _SampleWidgetState extends State<SampleWidget> {
  final controller = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextField(
      controller: controller,
      onSubmitted: (value) {
        final exp = MathNodeExpression.fromString(value);
        final result = exp.calc(MathVariableValues.none);
        controller.text = '$result';
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much, this answer was easy and effective.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function to calculate your example field and improve it for your needs.

```
int calculate(String textFieldInput) {
  List<String> inputList = textFieldInput.split(' ');

  int firstNumber = int.parse(inputList[0]);
  int secondNumber = int.parse(inputList[2]);
  String sign = '${inputList[1]}';

  int result = 0;

  if (sign == '+') {
    result = firstNumber + secondNumber;
  }

  return result;
}
```

Comment: This won't work for more complex calculation like "1 + 2 * 3".

Comment: yeah, it's true, but with a for loop and switch case will work for more complex calculations.